# Wordpress Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined on important school project site

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am currently working on a school project for which I have created a wordpress website. Until recently my website aaerexpress.studenthost.me worked perfectly, but after updating to wordpress 6 I first had the bug that elementor stopped working and now my entire website started to stop working. When I want to open my website I only get this error text:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WP_Taxonomy::reset_default_labels() in /home/vol14_4/studenthost.me/oosoh_31762467/htdocs/wp-includes/taxonomy.php:28 Stack trace: #0 /home/vol14_4/studenthost. me/oosoh_31762467/htdocs/wp-settings.php(402): create_initial_taxonomies() #1 /home/vol14_4/studenthost.me/oosoh_31762467/htdocs/wp-config.php(96): require_once(‘/home/vol14_4/s… ‘) #2 /home/vol14_4/studenthost.me/oosoh_31762467/htdocs/wp-load.php(50): require_once(‘/home/vol14_4/s…’) #3 /home/vol14_4/studenthost.me/oosoh_31762467/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once(‘/home/vol14_4/s. ..’) #4 /home/vol14_4/studenthost.me/oosoh_31762467/htdocs/index.php(17): require(‘/home/vol14_4/s..’) #5 {main} thrown in /home/vol14_4/studenthost.me/oosoh_31762467/htdocs/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, update WordPress manually.
There seems to be a problem updating.

[WordPress Manual Update Guide](https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#step-1-replace-wordpress-files)

If your problem persists, first rename the plugins folder through the host. If it does not work, do so with the themes folder.

If the problem is solved by renaming the plugins folder, enter the counter and then go to the plugins section.
And then reset the folder name to the previous state.
All plugins are now disabled
Just activate them one by one
To find the problem.

Comment: Stuff like that only happens to me when updating wordpress hosted on windows server instead of linux... manual update helped, thanks!

Comment: Somhow not checked my stackoferflow for a long time but this was exactly what solved the problem. The Project went well and worked at the time i had to show it to my teachers. Thnx so much for the perfect answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to downgrade the PHP version on my cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

For my case it was the php version, was running 7.4 and then downgraded to 7.3 and it all worked well after.